# Does different hardware spec affect the number of transactions a miner included in a block?

Tags: transactions, mining, blocks

I am a newbie so any insight would be appreciated!

The number of transactions included in a block could be determined by a number of factors:

1. The gas price set by the miner who validated that block. If the gas price that the sender is willing to pay for execution is lower than the gas price of the miner would accept, the transaction would never make it into a block.
2. The gas limit set by the miner. If the gas used of that block is very closed to the gas limit set, that would imply that the validator has to increase the gas limit if they want to include more transaction

On top of that, I am unsure if hardware spec will affect that number of transactions a miner included in a block. Assuming the validator didn't miss signing any blocks but would like to include more transaction in the block, is there any improvement that could be done in terms of hardware and how would it make a difference?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think so. Unless the configuration is changed, a hardware change is not going to increase the block size.